# How can I push just a local folder to my remote Cloud Foundry instance?

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I just want to **create a folder outside my war structure**. I need to replicate my local architecture using vmc or via manifest.yml

I want to create directories into the root of the remote system.

*For example*, in **Amazon Elastic Beanstalk** you can do this :

```
command: "cp -r .ebextensions/myConfig /var/"
```

Where "myConfig" is a Linked folder into my local strructure, and "var" is a remote folder for a Tomcat Based instance in Amazon.

Is there any way to do this in  Cloud Foundry?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can not modify the root filesystem. You get the directory that contains the application, and that can be modified at will but that's it.

Elastic Beanstalk gives you a vm which you can do WHATEVER you want. Cloud Foundry doesn't give you a vm; so it has limitations.